# What is the difference between splicing and superimposition?

Tags: terminology, mixing

In music editing, what is the difference between these two terms? Both involve overlaying some track onto another, but I don't see the difference, even though I am told by my professor there is one. Could anybody explain this to me?

Comment: 'Splicing' is a throwback to the days of tape, and physically cutting/taping together pieces of tape.  Thus this refers to the sequencing of audio.  'Superimposition', I'd imagine from the sound of it, refers to 'multitracking' - recording the audio of two sources simultaneously, so that you hear both recordings at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With spliced, you hear one then the other.

[image: spliced]

With superimposed, you hear both at the same time.

[image: superimposed]